# JavaScript trigonometric

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I'm working on some JavaScript and I've run across a problem with the math:

```
var p1 = {x:0,y:0}, p2 = {x:1,y:1};
return Math.sin(45) * Math.sqrt((Math.pow(p2.x-p1.x,2) + Math.pow(p2.y-p1.y,2)));
```

Returns 1.203359304667218

But when I do the same calculation on my calculator, it returns 1 which is what I expect this calculation to return. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: radians != degrees

Comment: ohh i thought it took degrees thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What mode did you work on with calculator?

Radians or Degrees?
Guess that could be your "problem" which may be solved easily :-)

Answer (score 3):

These are always useful and will likely avoid future confusion:

```
function sind(d) {
  return Math.sin(Math.PI*d/180.0); 
}

function cosd(d) {
  return Math.cos(Math.PI*d/180.0); 
}

function tand(d) {
  return Math.tan(Math.PI*d/180.0); 
}
```

Comment: @Murplyx Then do you care to bestow your wisdom onto the unknowing? Downvotes will not teach people anything, feedback will.

Answer (score 2):

```
var degreesToRadians = function (d) {
  return Math.PI * d / 180; 
}
```